# Website too slow after using htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently added a couple rewrite rules and since then my site has been too slow. What will be a more efficient way to use these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ videos.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ article.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ video.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure if this will solve your problem but there is a "known" performance degredation by using .htaccess for rewrites as stated in [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down
>   your Apache server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess
>   file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same
>   effect with better performance.

Hope this helps.